# Docker compose for AWS EC2 instance with ports limited to private IP address not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance with a public (elasticip) and private IP address. I would like to run a docker container with ports bound *only* to the private IP address.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    network_mode: host
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: npm
    ports:
      - "10.10.100.100:81:81" # internal IP address
```

My extarnal IP address (elasticIP) is something like 3.29.50.100.
I thought the above `10.10.100.100:81:81` would limit ingress traffic to my instance to only allow traffic from the 10.10.100.100 IP address, and deny all else. I added `network_mode: host` thinking that would solve the problem.

However, I can still access my container's service from the elasticIP address (eg. "http://3.29.50.100:81" and really any other address on the host, such as "http://127.0.0.1:81".

The Docker documentation seems to indicate that the above should work.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What the IP binding actually does is bind to the network interface that has that IP address. However your EC2 instance only actually has one network interface. The AWS network is doing a NAT to send traffic from the public IP to the private IP, so all traffic is still hitting that single network interface.

To do what you want via docker-compose, you would first have to assign a second Elastic Network Interface to the EC2 instance, without a public IP assigned to that ENI, and then bind to that.

---

However, there is a much simpler way to handle this sort of thing in AWS. You can simply update the security group of the EC2 instance so that the only inbound rule for port `81` specifies the CIDR block of your VPC. Then only requests that originated in your VPC will be able to access port `81` on the EC2 server. Any requests coming from outside the VPC would be blocked from accessing that port.